# Updating multiple branches in SourceTree

Tags: xcode, git, git-branch, atlassian-sourcetree

I am really new to SourceTree and was hoping someone could help me out.

I have made changes to my working copy and I need to commit and push my changes to multiple branches. How do I do this?

Right now I have my current branch under the 'Branches' header on the left and then I have multiple branches located under the 'Remotes' header.

So basically I want to push my changes to my current branch and also a few that are located in my remotes.

Thanks

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? I understand you need to checkout a branch and when you commit and push you can choose which branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can merge an existing branch into another, although I don't feel very confident doing this since I would really like to avoid conflicts or you can cherry pick specific commits from one branch and add them to another.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty well described answer: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-sourcetree-brances-to-merge-an-update/

Where I found Sourcetree confusing is that when you push on one branch it presents you with checkboxes so you can simultaneously push to multiple branches. I end up unchecking these and doing the merge as I would on command line, ie, as it is described in the link. If anyone else has insight into how the checkbox option works I'd love to know! If pushing to multiple at the same time is technically better than doing a merge after